# I'm getting a type error while building snfit-2.4.2

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

For my research study, I need to fit some Supernovae Light Curves (LC). For this purpose, there are some templates available to fit the SNe lightcurves. One such LC template fitter is the snfit-2.4.2 . While building 1it from the source I'm getting some errors, which is described below:

```
salt2extinction.cc:132:10: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand 

types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'})
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |     ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~
      |     |       |
      |     |       std::stringstream {aka std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>}
      |     std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
salt2extinction.cc:132:10: note: candidate: 'operator<<(int, int)' <built-in>
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
salt2extinction.cc:132:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'int'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:108:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:108:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&)' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)'}
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:117:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]'
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:117:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&)' {aka 'std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)'}
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:127:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:127:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)'
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:166:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:166:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'long int'
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:170:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:170:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'long unsigned int'
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:174:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:174:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'bool'
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:702,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:91:5: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
   91 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:92:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'short int'
   92 |     operator<<(short __n)
      |                ~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:181:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:181:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'short unsigned int'
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:702,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:105:5: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
  105 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:106:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'int'
  106 |     operator<<(int __n)
      |                ~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:192:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:192:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'unsigned int'
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:201:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:201:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'long long int'
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:205:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:205:37: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'long long unsigned int'
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:220:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:220:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'double'
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:224:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:224:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'float'
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:232:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:232:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'long double'
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:245:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:245:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'const void*'
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:702,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:119:5: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]'
  119 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:120:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__streambuf_type*' {aka 'std::basic_streambuf<char>*'}
  120 |     operator<<(__streambuf_type* __sbin)
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6416:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)'
 6416 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6416:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} is not derived from 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:217:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::error_code&)'
  217 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, const error_code& __e)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:217:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   cannot convert 'message' (type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}) to type 'const std::error_code&'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:506:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)'
  506 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, _CharT __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:506:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT' ('char' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>')
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:511:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char)'
  511 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:511:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   cannot convert 'message' (type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}) to type 'char'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:517:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char)'
  517 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:517:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   cannot convert 'message' (type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}) to type 'char'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:523:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, signed char)'
  523 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, signed char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:523:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   cannot convert 'message' (type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}) to type 'signed char'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:528:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char)'
  528 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, unsigned char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:528:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   cannot convert 'message' (type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}) to type 'unsigned char'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:548:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const _CharT*)'
  548 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const _CharT* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:548:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   mismatched types 'const _CharT*' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:702,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:321:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const char*)'
  321 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:321:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   cannot convert 'message' (type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}) to type 'const char*'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:565:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*)'
  565 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:565:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   cannot convert 'message' (type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}) to type 'const char*'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:578:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)'
  578 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const signed char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:578:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   cannot convert 'message' (type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}) to type 'const signed char*'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:583:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)'
  583 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const unsigned char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:583:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
salt2extinction.cc:132:13: note:   cannot convert 'message' (type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}) to type 'const unsigned char*'
  132 |     cerr << message << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from salt2extinction.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:691:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Ostream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type>::type std::operator<<(_Ostream&&, const _Tp&)'
  691 |     operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:691:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream: In substitution of 'template<class _Ostream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type>::type std::operator<<(_Ostream&&, const _Tp&) [with _Ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>&; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>]':
salt2extinction.cc:132:13:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:691:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:619: salt2extinction.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/salt/build/snfit-2.4.2/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:305: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/salt/build/snfit-2.4.2'
make: *** [Makefile:236: all] Error 2
```

The source file to build snfit-2.4.2 canbe downloaded from:
http://supernovae.in2p3.fr/salt/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=jla-installation.sh

I have tried to build this on three separate machines:
my own machine with :
AMD A8 7650 processor
Zorin 20.04 OS

My workstation #1 with:

Intel Xeon Octacore
Ubuntu 18.04.2

My workstation #2 with:

Intel Xeon Octacore
Ubuntu 20.04.2

In all these machines I'm getting the same problem.
I don't have much experience in C++.
Therefore, I'm not quite able to make sense of the issue to begin with.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to print the `stringstream`. No can do. You can print the `string` in the `stringstream`, `message.str()` , or directly from the `stringstream`'s internal buffer, `message.rdbuf()`. If this is code in the library itself... No <expletive deleted>ing clue what they did to make this work and why it doesn't extend to your code.

Comment: Just did a quick grep through their code and don't see an `operator <<` overload for `stringstream`. Possible someone left a file out or didn't test goodly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple fix is change the code to:

```
stringstream message;
message << "ERROR Salt2ExtinctionLaw::Read unknown version " << version;
cerr << message.str() << endl;
```